# Best method for making a MySQL query dynamic (e.g., update query parameters to show Previous Week)

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I have a query which calculates the total hours worked for the current week by task:

```
SELECT name AS 'Task Name'
       , sum(hours) AS `Total Hours`
        FROM time_records
        WHERE yearweek(record_date, 3) = yearweek(now(), 3)
        GROUP BY
        weekday(record_date), name
```

The WHERE clause specifies the current week:

```
WHERE yearweek(record_date, 3) = yearweek(now(), 3)
```

This data is displayed as a table using the MySQL query and a PDO statement.

I would now like to add an option for the viewer to see the previous week of data by clicking a link under the table (e.g., "Previous Week"). In order to show that data, I would need to update the WHERE clause to query for the previous week:

```
   WHERE yearweek(record_date, 3) = yearweek(now(), 3) - 1
```

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is? I would prefer to keep just one version of the overall query. One thought is to use PHP to add the "- 1" to the query, such as:

```
WHERE yearweek(record_date, 3) = yearweek(now(), 3) <?php if (prev) {echo "- 1" ;} ?>
```

I think this should work, but how can I determine the prev condition? Should I make the entire query be inside a function so that for the default it can be "Time_hours(0)" and for the previous it can be "Time_hours(1)" - or is there some better way?

I'm concerned about keeping the code manageable and following best practices. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: yearweek, of course, gives useless results for "last week" when you use it in the first week of a calendar year.

Comment: @OllieJones what would you recommend instead? I understand that it's something I will need to resolve before January

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try a query that has a parameter for the number of weeks ago you want to process.  YEARWEEK is a bad choice for weekly processing because it handles end-of-year rollovers poorly.

Try this, if your weeks begin on Sunday. This will give the current week.

```
select r.record_id, r.record_date, w.week weekstart
from record r
join (
    select 
      (FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -1, 7)) 
           - interval 0 week) week
 )w
where record_date >= w.week
  and record_date < w.week + interval 1 week
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c487/1/0

If you want, let's say, one week ago, change `- interval 0 week` to `- interval 1 week` in your query. See this fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c487/2/0

You can put an an arbitrary number of weeks ago, even weeks that span year ends. See here for `interval -42 week` for example.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c487/3/0

The expression `FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -1, 7))` rounds the current date down to the previous Sunday.  If you want to round it to the previous Monday, use `FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -2, 7))`.  For example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c487/8/0

Comment: great - thanks for the tip, I am going to make the 1 or 0 be passed by a function which will differentiate between current week (0) and last week (1). Thanks again!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your join condition - there is no ON for this join clause. I'm using it in a slightly augmented text and the WHERE of the query is not recognizing the w.week value. Any insight into what type of join this is? Is it MySQL native? I have some other joins in my query and I'm getting errors trying to add this join in.

Comment: Don't change the WHERE clause. There's no hint that arbitrary weeks are a requirement, so use two views instead. One view for the current week, one view for the previous week.

Comment: You're correct that there's no join `ON` condition. That makes it into a so-called  `outer join`. That is, the single row of the "w" virtual table is joined to every row of the rest of the table.  This is a slightly counterintuitive concept, but it makes the `WHERE` clause a little easier to read.  Also, it doesn't have a performance problem.

Comment: @Catcall, you could write your own answer to the question to explain what you mean. Just be sure to test it for the year-end and year-begin rollover cases.

Comment: The OP doesn't need *another* answer. Just needs you to wrap your SELECT statements in CREATE VIEW...AS. Application code can then just select from the appropriate view instead of passing hard-to-read SQL to the DBMS.  (Hard to read, because almost all SQL that does date arithmetic is hard to read.)